# Abbreviations of St, Ave, Blvd, etc., for intersections and plurals of

Tags: abbreviations

For a document I'm preparing that includes photos, each photo caption includes the approximate street intersection from which the photo was taken, e.g.:

> ...., Market St & Grant Ave looking east.

In cases where both streets are of the same "type" (both "St" or "Ave"), I omit the first and pluralize the second, e.g.:

> ...., Market & Kearny Sts looking west.

Is that an OK thing to do?  (I couldn't find this addressed in *The Chicago Manual of Style*. If it's in there, please give the citation.)

One thing I did find in the CMOS is that I should put the period after the abbreviations, e.g.:

> ...., Market St. & Grant Ave. looking east.

If I do that, what is the proper plural?  Still just the period after the abbreviation and no other punctuation?

> ...., Market & Kearny Sts. looking west.

Do the same rules apply for intersection abbreviations in the main body text? Thanks.

Comment: Personally I prefer 'Str.' as abbreviation for 'street'. 'St.' usually means 'Saint'.

Comment: @WS2: I worked for decades in the UK bus industry, often dealing with route planning, timetabling, etc. I don't *ever* recall anyone using ***Str*** for ***Street***.

Comment: In the US St. is the US postal service abbreviation for street.

Comment: @Paul: Someone else may be able to provide a better justification (or maybe even disagree with my position), but I think it's a *very bad idea* to write "Market & Kearny Sts" instead of "Market St & Kearny St".

Comment: @David M: Actually, in the US, the Post Office doesn't use periods and prefers all CAPS -- see CMOS, 10.34.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You are no doubt right about St. But I had a schoolmaster who taught Latin and Religious Instruction (as it was then known), who would never use the abbreviation 'St.' for 'Saint'. He would insist we wrote 'S.Paul', 'S.Matthew' etc. His rationale was that 'St.' stood for 'street'. Since I have never felt inclined to continue his 'S.' affectation, I have alternatively used 'Str' for 'street'.

Comment: @Paul My bad. I had no period originally and then I hedged!  Should have gone with the gut.

Comment: @WS2: It would appear there are quite a few places called **Saint Johns Street** on the Internet at large. Googling "**St Johns Street**" or "**Saint Johns St**" finds lots of references (more for the second), but I couldn't see any obviously relevant hits for "**St Johns St**" (there were a lot of "not relevant" hits, so I didn't plough through them all).

Comment: @Paul: Contrary to the only answer you have thus far, I wouldn't advise using periods. Searching Google Books for ["Fifth Ave and 59th St"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Fifth+Ave+and+59th+St%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), for example, shows that both forms are used. But it seems to me the ones with periods are less common. Certainly they aren't used in most UK public timetables, etc. (besides which I just think they look clumsy! :)

Comment: And what about the other part of my question, using a single "Sts" when both "roads" are of the same type?

Comment: @FumbleFingers It is very rare (in New Yorkese)  to put the Avenue name first unless you spell it out that you're breaking convention.  (As a matter of fact, I and others have commented on your specific example in the past as being odd.  We decided it's because their building entrance is located on 5th Avenue). And, the AP manual of style says to put the periods in when abbreviating. I admit that I would never do so naturally either, but that is what a well respected authority says.

Comment: @David M: My link 3 comments above is an extreme example of how bad Google Books "guestimates" can be. On the first page of results it says "about 21,000 results", but if you scroll to the *second* page it admits there are in fact only 16 in total. Google Internet (which may or may not be a bit better in this respect! :) claims "about 4,860 results" for the search string **Grand Army Plaza "Fifth Ave and 59th St"**, as opposed to 9,970  for what you say is the more normal order - **Grand Army Plaza "59th St and Fifth Ave"**. Whatever - Wikipedia's article on the plaza doesn't use periods.

Comment: @Fumble I agree the periods should be burned in the fires of Hades, but they are recommended by style guides. Hence my assertion.  And, Google actually does print their address that way, IIRC. We've always hated it.  But it's in the 20s somewhere, not 59th St

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that there are several answers to this question:

The least formal approach:

Omit St. altogether.

> Corner of Market and Kearney
>   -Or-
>   Market St. and Kearney

I don't think you need St. on both unless a road with the same name which is an Ave. crosses it somewhere else.

In New York City, we always go St. & Ave. as a convention.

So, you would say 60th and 2nd.

A more formal approach:

[Per the AP manual of style](http://www.buffalo.edu/toolbox/editorial/ap_style.php)

Write out the word Street or Avenue in any instance where an exact address is not given.

> Market Street and Kearney Street
>   -Or-
>   Market Street, 700 block, facing East.

But, abbreviate when there is an exact address:

> 423 West Mercy St.
>   Chicago, IL 12345

Comment: The location is almost _never_ an actual corner; it's just the closest intersection. (If it were an actual corner, I'd feel compelled to specify _which_ corner, e.g., "NW corner of ....") If you read my question carefully, you'll see that I'm _not_ putting "St." on both when they match. "Broadway" (at least the one in NYC) is kind of a special case since it's famous -- it doesn't need further qualification.

Comment: Some London thoroughfares have no street, avenue, hill or lane designation e.g. Piccadilly, Cheapside, London Wall, The Strand, Embankment, Knightsbridge, Bishopsgate, etc.

Comment: Ordinarily, I would say to use St (period optional) on each of the choices. However, the streets you mention are in San Francisco and local practice is to omit street, avenue, etc., with a few exceptions from ambiguity or custom (e.g., Maiden Lane, once a red-light district). If you leave them out, you will look hip; put them in, you will look like out-of-towners.

Comment: It's a fairly formal bit of writing just like the captions you might find next to photographs hanging in a museum. I don't think museums care much about being hip.

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas In the case you are describing, not being a corner.  I would say:  Market St. between x and y facing east.

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas We'd be just as apt to say 24th and 1st without the Ave, too.

Comment: @DavidM: regarding between, that doesn't solve the problem, e.g., "Market St between 3rd & 4th Sts" or "Market St between 3rd St & 4th St." Besides, I need to keep the locations short to fit in the captions, hence my use of the nearest intersection.

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas I have seen similar things that note the block of street addresses as I said above.  Market St. 700 block facing East.  That gives a very specific location.

Comment: Except to me (and I imagine most people), it's hard to know where the "700 block" is whereas an intersection is easier to place. Look: I'm not asking for an _alternate_ way of doing this. I'm asking for (a) whether it's OK to elide the first "St" if both are Streets and whether I should used periods.

Comment: @pauljlucas Per the AP manual of style [the words should not be abbreviated when a complete address is not given](http://www.buffalo.edu/toolbox/editorial/ap_style.php). So this, in a round about way, solves your problem.

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas I hope you find my recent edit helpful. I'm really trying to be helpful and not pedantic. The problem is that Sts. means Saints to most people. [For example this.](http://stsphilipandjamesschool.com)